# How to disable all default keystrokes on Gtk

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm writing a source code editor, and I want to disable any of the pre-defined keystrokes, e.g Ctrl-V for paste, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the way to do this: Return boolean `True` from the method which handles the `key-press-event`. Any value that doesn't evaluate to true passes control back to Gtk.

In the particular way I implement this editor, the `key-press-event` signal of the toplevel vindow is connected to the method `__key_event_handler`, which basically filters all the keystrokes, modified with either Ctrl or Alt keys and returns True after processing the input, or just passes the control back to Gtk otherwise. This way, I can manage all the modified keystrokes, which are meant to be editor commands, and not need to handle insertion of normal characters.

Comment: Doesn't `Gtk.TextView` do much more than just handling bindings in `key-press-event`?

Comment: @doublep , Here, the `key-press-event` belongs to the toplevel window. I will extend this answer with some detail. And yes, probably Gtk.TextView (GtkSource.View in my case, which inherits from it) has a lot of functionalities, but in this case I don't want any functionality to be accesible without me defining an accesor method to it, as this is required for custamization possibilities to be as nearly great as i.e. Emacs.